# Lisp Append Not Working Properly

Tags: lisp, append

Hi I am trying append a simple element to a lisp list.

```
(append queue1 (pop stack1))
```

I thought the above code would append the first element of stack1 to queue1. Does `queue1` need to be non nil? Thanks.

Comment: you really should to read an introductory book

Comment: appending to the end of Lisp lists is not a good idea

Comment: APPEND returns a list that has the argument lists appended - (append list1 list2 list3) -> a list with the elements of list1 and list2 and  list3

Comment: appending empty lists returns the empty list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append *returns* the concatenated list (`queue1` with the first element of `stack1` appended).  It does not modify queue1.

The destructive equivalent of append is nconc: this appends to the list "in place."

Comment: So to append to a list I should simply do (nconc queue1 '4) to append the number 4 to the list queue1. Also what if nconc is nil, will it still append? Thanks

Comment: Yes, (nconc queue1 '4) will recycle queue1.  Idiomatically however you should still work with the returned value rather than relying on the side-effect.  Sorry, I'm not sure what would happen if you passed nil (though I assume it wouldn't work on the nil literal): spin up your Lisp implementation and try it I guess!

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which Lisp do you mean, but in Common Lisp at least:

1. APPEND concatenates lists, so all its arguments has to be lists, *not* atoms. If you really wanted to append an element to the list you would have to do `(append list1 (list element))`. This is not a good idea because in most Lisps lists are single linked, and an entire list will have to be traversed to append to the end. Usually one would append to the front with CONS and then reverse the list when done, but this obviously will not work for queues.
2. APPEND does not modify its arguments. NCONC is a destructive function. While I believe that NCONC in particular is [specified](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) to do more or less what one would expect, most destructive functions are allowed to **destroy** their arguments, to reuse their memory, but no necessarily leave anything coherent behind.
3. Lists in Common Lisp are implemented as chains of cons cells or nil, which means that their behaviour has some quirks relating to the latter. If you want a list acting more as you would expect from other languages then use a list abstract data structure. More so if you want a queue with constant append to the end. There are many imperative data structures available in [cl-containers](http://www.cliki.net/cl-containers) system, and functional data structures in [FSet](http://www.cliki.net/FSet).